# Concatenate data frames together based on similar column values

Tags: r

Specifically, say I had three data frames `d1, d2, d3`:

`d1`:

```
       X     Y    Z    value
1      0    20   135    43
2      0     4   105    50
3      5    18    20    10
...
```

`d2`:

```
       X     Y    Z    value
1      0    20   135    15
2      0     4   105    14
3      2     9    12    16
...
```

`d3`:

```
       X     Y    Z    value
1      0    20   135    29
2      2     9    14    16
...
```

I want to be able to combine these data frames such that each row of the combined data frame consists of three values, based on all unique X, Y, Z combinations. If such an X, Y, Z combination does not exist in one of the original data frames then I just want it to have a value of null (or some arbitrarily low number if that isn't possible). So I'd want an output of:

`dfinal`:

```
       X     Y    Z    value1  value2  value3
1      0    20   135     43      15      29
2      0     4   105     50      14     null
3      5    18    20     10     null    null
4      2     9    12    null     16     null
5      2     9    14    null    null     16
...
```

Is there any efficient way of doing this? I've tried doing this instead using `data.table` which seemed more suited for this but have yet to figure out how.

Comment: Maybe @http://stackoverflow.com/a/26738724/709777 could be useful for you, look at reshape

Comment: This actually works much better than merge in terms of efficiency. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
?merge
```

Should do the trick?

```
 By default the data frames are merged on the columns with names they both have, but separate specifications of the columns can be given by by.x and by.y.
```

So:

```
merge(d1,d2, by=c("X","Y","Z"))
```

And you can include all=TRUE, to have complete rows.
The missing data will be NA

```
    merge(d1,d2, by=c("X","Y","Z"), all=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at dplyr and its join methods. I wrote a small example:

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)

d1 <- data.table(X = c(1,2,3), Y = c(2,3,4), Z = c(8,3,9), value = c(22,3,44))
d2 <- data.table(X = c(1,4,3), Y = c(2,6,4), Z = c(8,9,9), value = c(44,22,11))

d2 <- rename(d2, value2 = value)


full_join(d1,d2)
```

output:

```
  X Y Z value value2
1 1 2 8    22     44
2 2 3 3     3     NA
3 3 4 9    44     11
4 4 6 9    NA     22
```